# Replace one URL with another by using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

**Current situation**

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=Portal [R=301,L]
```

When a user comes to the website and goes to the "root" url of the domain (RegExp "^$") he's redirected to /index.php?page=Portal

That's working.

Now we have "index.php?page=Portal" in the google index and we have tons of links to that page on various locations all over the internet.

**Intended new situation**

We want the portal page to show up on the root url - no redirect. That's no problem... Just remove the redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=Portal [L]
```

Now we also want the old url to redirect to the new location, and that's where I fail but can't see why:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=Portal$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.jacatu.de/? [R=301,L]
```

As soon as I do this I end up in a redirect loop:

[image]

(When I change to 302 in .htaccess I see 302 redirects, so the loop really seems to be caused by mod_rewrite)

But why? All rules are marked as **last** [L] - so I think I can rule out that rule 2 triggers rule 1.

Comment: You may want to enable mod_rewrite logging (RewriteLogLevel 2 + RewriteLog /path/to/logfile) before assuming anything. I had several mod_rewrite problems that were solved just by reading the mod_rewrite logs.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled logging as suggested by [Jacek Prucia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463698/jacek-prucia) and in fact it looked like having [L] in the URL doesn't stop execution. Both rules were processed.

I now changed the first rewrite to

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=Portal&int=1 [L]
```

so that it doesn't match the RewriteCond of the internal rewrite so theoretically my problem is solved. It would be nice to know, though, why it did what it did. :)